# MongodDB startup Failed in 32 bit Cents OS

Tags: mongodb

I've been facing below error while issuing service mongod start command.

Downloaded & set up done from this site : http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/

Could any one tell where it is going mistake ?

Comment: here is the log :Log

I2014-08-20T11:59:07.607+0530 ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2014-08-20T11:59:07.655+0530 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=17248 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongo 32-bit host=localhost.localdomain
2014-08-20T11:59:07.655+0530 [initandlisten]
2014-08-20T11:59:07.655+0530 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a 32 bit MongoDB binary.
2014-08-20T11:59:07.655+0530 [initandlisten] **       32 bit builds are limited to less than 2GB of data (or less with --journal).

Comment: 2014-08-20T11:59:07.655+0530 [initandlisten] **       Note that journaling defaults to off for 32 bit and is currently off.
2014-08-20T11:59:07.655+0530 [initandlisten] **       See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/32bit
2014-08-20T11:59:07.656+0530 [initandlisten]
2014-08-20T11:59:07.656+0530 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.4
2014-08-20T11:59:07.656+0530 [initandlisten] git version: 3a830be0eb92d772aa855ebb711ac91d658ee910

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the 64-bit version(you have downloaded the obsolete 32-bit version). The 32-bit version tends to support on 2GB of data and Journaling is turned off as well and hence not suitable for production environments.

Comment: My OS is 32 bit Cent OS 6.5 final